# Added input-field using before() does not trigger on focus()

Tags: jquery, input, focus, input-field

I have some code where I use the `before()` method to insert an `input-field` amongst other things. But for some reason the `input-fields` created dynamically does not trigger on `$("input").focus()`.

How do I get the new input-fields to trigger on `focus()`?

Comment: please post your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For dynamically created tags you should bind the events using delegates,
try

```
$(document).on( "focus", "your input selector", function() {

});
```

Comment: Thanks you so much! Both for the correct answer and for the very quick help! I'll mark this as accepted answer when I can (~10 min) :)